# Pop Up Window Data Variable Passing

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, database, popup

I am creating a web application for my company that needs to deal with form processing and database manipulation. The application is implemented using .NET Framework 3.5 using C# and Visual Studio 2008 as the IDE and Microsoft SQL Server 2005 as the database.

Here is my problem:

1. I have a **lot of forms**
2. But my boss only want me to create **a single page for the database
   processing** (easier to extend in the future)

I figured out the only way to solve this problem is by having only 1 .aspx file (that contains everything about the database) and having it invoked as a pop up window everytime a forms need to deal with the database.

Here is another problem of mine:

1. Due to stateless nature of HTTP, I am **unable to process and pass
   variable** between 2 different windows.
2. I managed to create certain Javascript functions and have the
   variable transferred on display, however it can only pass a variable
   that is the primary key in the table. To process other columns in
   the table is possible but as the consequence I have to write a very
   long inline script in my .aspx page and after it is compiled people
   can easily view how to access my company database easily. Hence, I
   don't favor this (beside to deal with 1 form, I need to create a
   long code already, imagine if i have more than 1000 forms!)

So there are two ways you guys can help me:

1. Suggest another way other than popping up a new window for my
   problem, maybe even advise on how it's implemented.
2. If you think popping up is the solution, you mind to **share some
   snippets that can help me figure out the variable passing between
   two different windows**. I can use some advise especially from some
   Javascript expert on this :).

Note: Solution must be workable in ASP.NET Framework 3.5 and tested using IE browser version: 8.

> P.S: This is a short explanation about my application flow
>
> 1. Let's say I entered data about a product (it has few properties id, name, price, etc) into the database
> 2. Later on somehow I want to edit one or few properties of that product, so I have to launch a form which called "editor.aspx"
> 3. Instead of entering the product id (which is the primary key) into the form (and edit the data based on the entered product id) and risking to miscalculately edit the correct data, I provide a small button in the form (let's name it btSearch), that will launch a new popup window which contains the gridview of the database of all product (with selection enabled)
> 4. Now I just need to browse through the gridview, select a particular row, it will close the popup and I expect to see few data from that row appeared on my original page (in the textboxes/labels)

I hope my explanation above clears the air, thank you.

Comment: "Javascript" is one word, not two.

Comment: You should consider one class for DB operations, not page. And all the pages should call this class when they intend to do. I hope I am clear on ur requirement.

Comment: Okay thank's for your comment, FYI I actually do have one class that contains all my SQL manipulation strings. But very sorry, I mistakenly forgot to tell this in my question. Actually, what I mean with 'page' in my question is indeed a .aspx page that will display the database (as a gridview) and allow user to pick(select) any value from any row/column. For sure picking the value is not a big deal, but I found hard time to transfer the picked value back to the parent page. Hope this clears the air :)

Comment: Can you give one example of all your forms where this will be used?  I'm having a hard time understanding what you mean by one form for all of your data processing.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your interest. I updated the question already. Do check :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently wrote something like that: A database handler as aspx file. But i invoked it by using ajax / jquery.

When my aspx file is done, i write something to the response stream, some code, a json string, what ever.

Example:

```
$.post("yourdatabasehandler.aspx", { name: "John", lastname: "Smith" }, function(data) {
    alert("Response from page: " + data);
  });
```

In that example, name and lastname are values that are posted to your site. You can access them like that:

```
string name = Request.Params["name"]
// Do your database , validation and whatever logic here
Response.Write("Cool dude");
```

The above javascript will alert "Cool dude" after your databasehandler is done. Inside your javascript you can react to the response how ever you want - For example reload a page.

Hope that helps? Regards

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. To be honest, I am not familiar with Jquery/Ajax. Will sure revert back to you, once I tried this code anyway :).

Answer (score 1):

> "1. Due to stateless nature of HTTP, I am unable to process and pass
>   variable between 2 different windows."

You very wrong with this comment to start with, trying MSDN and ASP.Net ["How to pass values between ASP.Net Web pages"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). Passing between Windows only requires a little bit more thought and possibly a little Javascript to refresh a parent windows or cause a postback on a shild window etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I actually read this tutorial already. I in fact implemented it as interim solution for my boss. In this interim solution, I use "Response.Redirect" to move between one page to another. And by storing values in session, I successfully pass value between those pages. However my boss insisted that I use popup! And so far I haven't successfully implement any working solutions.

Comment: You can store objects in an array and hold it in the Application state with a unique key as a reference, pass this key as a parameter when opening the popup, both pages have access to the same application state if they are being served from the same server, if not you will have to persist the data elsewhere.

Comment: Have you shown your boss the AjaxControlToolkit modal popup? http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the comment, anyway I think that AjaxControlToolkit will only work to popup any asp/html element from respective pages. Whereas, I am actually intending to launch a pop up of a new page (different 1). But thank you for suggesting it. Have played around with it just now, it seemed to be a very powerful tool. For sure in the future I will consider using it for my next project :).

Comment: Btw the http application state and keys seem very prormising, will sure try about it :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a popup window, you can always use QueryStrings to pass a value going to your popup.

```
window.open("popup_page.aspx?id=" + id + "&name=" + name)
```

to access it in popup_page.aspx

```
string sID = Request.QueryString("id");
string sName = Request.QueryString("name");
```

Update: if you're using IE the this might help you.

```
function ShowPopup(strMessage) 
{   
   var returnValue= window.showModalDialog("popup_page.aspx");

}
```

popup_page.aspx

```
<asp:Button ID="btnReturnValue" runat="server" Text="Proceed" OnClientClick="window.returnValue='some message';window.close();" />
```

Note: Please note this only works in **IE**, so I suggest consider using the followings instead:

[jQuery](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation)

[AjaxControlToolkit ModalPopup](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/modalpopup/modalpopup.aspx)

I personally suggest the use of jQuery. :)

Comment: Hi, thank's for the reply. Actually passing the data from parent window to popup window is possible. Yet Passing the data back from popup window to parent window is something yet I can't do.

Comment: Hey, thank's for the update.. I found it very helpful. Regards

Answer (score 0):

Thank's for all answers, comments. rates, and feedback. Just now I found a very helpful link [here](http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/282/passing-value-from-popup-window-to-parent-form39s-textbox/.). Basically the answer is based on that particular code. I just need to alter some part.

```
<script language="javascript">

function GetRowValue(val)
{
    window.opener.document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TextBox2").value = val;
   // make sure you change the TextBoxId as respective to your creation 
    window.close();
}

</script>

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
<Columns>
<!-- Reserve the code below, as after you configure data source you -->
<!-- will alter this code drastically therefore-->
<!--you have to make sure to paste this code --> 
<!-- again inside this Gridview element once you configure your data source -->
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <AlternatingItemTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="btnSelect" runat="server" Text="Select" />
        </AlternatingItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="btnSelect" runat="server" Text="Select" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
<!-- This part must be reserved -->
</Columns>
```

Also remember to specify the connection string and the sql command in the datasource.

The rest just follow that tutorial and copy paste the code entirely.